# Вопрос по созданию приложения в Android Studio

Tags: android, view

Всем привет. В Google Play есть View с вкладками "Главная, игры, фильмы и т.д.". Как сделать так же? Похоже на TabItem, но вроде не то. Я, скажем так, новичок в создании Android-приложений. Может кто проконсультирует, подскажет?

Comment: View со словами "Главная, игры, фильмы и т.д." листается. Меня интересует именно это. Именно View можно листать и видеть, что ещё на нём расположено. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Вы имеете ввиду `ViewPager` ? Об этом есть куча уроков. Начать знакомство можете [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: View со словами "Главная, игры, фильмы и т.д." листается. Меня интересует именно это. Именно View можно листать и видеть, что ещё на нём расположено. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Посмотрите тут - http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, используется `ViewPager` + `SlidingTabLayout`.

В интернете можно найти множество примеров реализации. Например: [ссылка](http://www.fandroid.info/android-sliding-tabs-razdvizhnye-vkladki-v-stile-material-design/).